# Remove underscore from string except from the link in string

Tags: c#, regex, string, html-email

I have a text paragraph which may contain some url links. I need to remove the underscores "_" only from that string.

But as I told text have url links and url links may also have underscores but their underscores should not be removed.

The links can be in any order i.e. there might be some text above or below those links, basically this is the email text content which would be sent in emails.

I was thinking to use some regex but that would remove the underscores from the links as well which I don't want. I was thinking to take out those links and then remove the underscores and then again add back the links in the text but as I told the links can be in different orders i.e. the text is dynamic content.

Any guidance would be appreciated and I will take it from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of a variable width negative look-behind `(?<!\b(?:https?://\S*|www\.))_`:

```
(?<!\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S*)_
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cb(%3f%3ahttps%3f%3a%2f%2f%7cwww%5c.)%5cS*)_&i=Some_string+http%3a%2f%2fex.com%2fnew_path%2ft.php+www.google.com+and+more_texts&r=)

This regex will match any `_` that is not preceded with `http://`/`https://`/`www.` followed by any number of any characters other than whitespace (`\S*`).

C#:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S*)_", string.Empty);
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Your answer is 99% perfect, in your demo you please change this- www.google.com to this - www.goo_gle.com. This is also matching, can you please check this.

Comment: Sorry, it does not now, I misplaced `\S*` at the beginning. Please refresh and click the demo link again.

Comment: Yes, it works now, I refreshed the page. This is perfect, thank you.

Comment: I can accept your answer in next 5 mins, as per SO :)

Comment: I am getting small issue in this i.e. how can I exclude email addresses just like url links in the Regex. Sorry, I am not good with Regex.

Comment: Use [`(?<!\b(?:https?://|www\.|\S+@)\S*)(?!_\S*@[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+)_`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cb(%3f%3ahttps%3f%3a%2f%2f%7cwww%5c.%7c%5cS%2b%40)%5cS*)(%3f!_%5cS*%40%5b%5e.%5cs%5d%2b%5c.%5b%5e.%5cs%5d%2b)_&i=Some_string+http%3a%2f%2fex.com%2fnew_path%2ft.php+www.google.com+and+more_texts+my_name%40new_mail.com&r=).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I think you understood me wrong, I meant just like underscores are ignored in the url links, could it also be ignored in the email address as well? Right now the email address gets replaced with string.Empty. Can you please help :)

Comment: I just tested your Regex pattern is working fine on Regex Tester, I think something else is wrong, which I will check.

Comment: In case of trouble, please post your code in the question.